# Updating Dell PowerEdge firmware on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dell, dell-poweredge, ubuntu-10.04

The company I work for recently got hands on a batch of second hand PowerEdge SC1425 machines. We'd like to put these to good use. Our operating system of choice is Ubuntu Server 10.04 64-bit, which installs just peachy on this type of machine.

Now I'd like to install the firmware updates from Dell, which are apparently marked as recommended. This includes the updates for the BIOS, the BMC, and possibly some other hardware.

I find it incredibly difficult to locate the files on the Dell website, and install any of them on an Ubuntu system:

- I downloaded the file `OM_6.2.0_SUU_A01.iso`.

  - I believe I've read that the SUU DVD should be able to update any recent PowerEdge. Is this correct?
  - Is this the latest version? Besides the version number, does `A01` have any meaning?
  - Is this image bootable? (At the moment, I just nosed around with a loop device mount.)
- Running `/bin/bash ./suu` from the DVD, I get:

  ```
  # /bin/bash ./suu
  ./suu: line 262: ./java/linux/i386/bin/java: No such file or directory
  ```

  The file exists and is executable, though. But I cannot execute it directly from the shell either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's what you're looking for, but I tend to upgrade PowerEdge systems using the OMSA live CD from [the OpenManage Dell site](http://linux.dell.com/files/openmanage-contributions/). I just boot it up (it's centOS-based), downloaded the needed upgrade files for Red Hat, run them, and then reboot back to the original system.

Comment: This seems to have worked just fine. I don't believe I actually used any of the tools on the CD, but the live environment was good enough to run SUU from the loop mounted image. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Shteef - oh, so you mean those round things that come with servers are not alternatives for cork coasters? they are one of the first things that go to the trashcan during unboxing of a new server.

Answer (score 4):

`The file exists and is executable, though. But I cannot execute it directly from the shell either.`

You are likely missing the 32-bit compatibility libraries, preventing the 32-bit Java from executing. In the documentation, it explicitly states that SUU is a 32-bit application and what the dependencies are for running in a 64-bit environment.

These are the dependencies as documented for Red Hat. I suppose that they ought to be available for Ubuntu under the same or similar names; procmail, glibc, compat-libstdc++-296, compat-libstdc++-33, libstdc++, zlib, and libxml2.

I know this question has long since been answered, but it took me a while to figure it out so I am answering for the benefit of others that may be searching this question.

Comment: It's been a while, but I wouldn't be surprised if that was my problem. I never thought 'no such file or directory' could mean that.

Comment: You wouldn't think, but you know the file does exist because you can see it.  Error handling isn't always written well enough to give the most descriptive feedback.  If you get a chance, try it and let us know since it could help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Fine Manual worked for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge 2850. I didn't even have to use the kernel boot option reboot=bios. No fussing with floppy disk images, dosemu, or other wackiness.

http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Tech/libsmbios_dellBiosUpdate

The instructions lists where to get the raw BIOS on the linux.dell.com website.

Comment: The link is 404'ed.   Wish folks would copy the content to SF instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to mound the image with -o exec  to enable execution of the application from that dvd  (or iso image)

Comment: I didn't find this necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

I always burn the SUU to disk and boot to it.  From there you can navigate the Dell menus, scan for needed firmware updates, and install them.  Reboot and you are good to go.

Comment: The SUU has OS and RAID config items on the same menu as the firmware. That is pretty ambiguous to me. When you "apply", does it modify the raid or start prepping for an OS install? I have a fully configured OS I don't want the SUU to anything except update firmware.

Comment: You are talking about the Systems Management and Configuration disk if you see those options.  In that utility you have 3 options. Firmware, which you connect to a repository, the RAID config, and then the OS config.  The SUU disk has a repository and is for firmware updates.  # ./suu -u